# Android CoordinatorLayout : ToolBar scroll only when list starts scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-recyclerview, android-support-design

I am using Toolbar in my application and using this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) i am hiding tool bar,it works perfect as expected.But when the List has only one /two items, there is no need to scroll the tool bar as there is enough space at the bottom.

The idea behind hiding the tool bar is to make use of tool bar space when list items beyond the screen height.But when the list items are few i.e less than the device screen height i do not want to scroll the Tool bar.How do i achieve it. TIA.

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/no_matches_found"
    android:visibility="gone" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally this logic worked for me.

1.Get the height of the recycleview list item and multiply with total item count.

2. Get the height of the display.

Based on the above two parameters set the scroll flags to tool bar,like the below code :

```
private void setScrollIfNeeded() {
    int viewItemHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dp); // list item size is fixed in this case
    int totalCount = mRecycleView.getAdapter().getItemCount();

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    int listHeight = viewItemHeight * totalCount;
    if (listHeight > height) {
        setScrollFlags(true);
    } else {
        setScrollFlags(false);
    }
}

public void setScrollFlags(boolean set) {
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params =
            (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) mTooolbar.getLayoutParams();

    if (set)
        params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL
                | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);
    else

        params.setScrollFlags(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to check the toolbar height (you need to add this metric to the list height) and to update the toolbar layoutparams in the setScrollFlags method.

To compute toolbar height, an easy way is this:

```
final TypedArray styledAttributes = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{
      R.attr.actionBarSize});
int toolbarHeight = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
styledAttributes.recycle();
```

To update lp, you need to add this line at the end of the method.

```
mTooolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
```

full code:

```
private void setScrollIfNeeded() {
    int viewItemHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dp); // list item size is fixed in this case
    int totalCount = mRecycleView.getAdapter().getItemCount();

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    int listHeight = viewItemHeight * totalCount;

   final TypedArray styledAttributes = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{
          R.attr.actionBarSize});
    int toolbarHeight = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
    styledAttributes.recycle();

    listHeight += toolbarHeight;


    if (listHeight > height) {
        setScrollFlags(true);
    } else {
        setScrollFlags(false);
    }
}

public void setScrollFlags(boolean set) {
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params =
            (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) mTooolbar.getLayoutParams();

    if (set){
        params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL
                | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);
    } else {
        params.setScrollFlags(0);
    }
    mTooolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```